# Ajustar tamaño de una tabla de imagenes en android, de forma que sea uniforme en los distintos tamaños de pantallas

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Dentro de un `GridLayout` tengo definidos images de este estilo:

```
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/algo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/imagen"
            android:background="#000"
/>
```

Para cada imagen usada tengo su equivalente en mdpi, hdpi y xhdpi. El problema es que la tabla en pantallas pequeñas se ve incompleta (hasta llega a faltar una columna) y en pantallas grande me sobra mucho espacio, realmente su tamaño es muy desuniforme en cada posible pantalla.

Creía que este problema se resolvía al generar las distintas resoluciones. No sé si las propiedades width y height de cada imagen las debería manipular con un tamaño en dp y generar distintos layout o cómo resolver este problema para que sea mas uniforme la visualización de la tabla en distintas pantallas.

[image: Distintas vistas, algunos casos hasta falta una columna]

Comment: Si bien se entiende perfectamente el problema, quizás ayudaría a ver el problema si insertaras una imagen de cómo se ve.

Comment: Hola , he agregado una imagen.

Comment: Añade el código de tu layout, así se puede determinar más el problema, el gridlayout como lo tienes definido su ancho match parent?

Comment: En la noche lo agregó tal cual, mientras debo decir que el gridlayout es wrap content en sus medidas y está contenido dentro de un linear layout que si es match parent

Answer (score 1):

La mejor opción en este caso puede ser que uses match_parent sobre todo para el GridLayout en lugar de usar wrap_content, de esa forma podrás conseguir que siempre ocupe el máximo de la pantalla, si sigue sin verse toda la tabla seguramente sera porque las imágenes son demasiado grandes y no caben, en este caso te recomiendo usar un scrollview.

Comment: Se visualizo de la misma manera, pareciera que Android me usa siempre el mismo tamaño de imágenes para cualquier tipo de tamaño de pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Esto sería un *3x3* que se adapta a cualquier tamaño.

En resumen es un contenedor *LinearLayout* en el que sus elementos tienen de tamaño la proporción correspondiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/prueba"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="33.33"
        android:weightSum="100"
    >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="33.33"
        android:weightSum="100"
    >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="33.33"
        android:weightSum="100"
    >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```